# How can I check if email or sms have been sent in Corona?

Tags: email, sms, coronasdk

Hi there I need to know if there is any way to check the status of an e-mail or sms in Corona SDK. I need to be sure if the user sent the email or sms to give him a gift, an extra live or something like that.
So, how can I be sure that the sending process completed successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't check this. Corona just start an intent and launch the mail or sms app but the user  will decide what he wants to do next. You should try to contact Corona staff or make a feature request here http://feedback.coronalabs.com/forums/188732-corona-sdk-feature-requests-feedback but from my own experience I can tell you that it can take even an year until they will add this new feature. Last months they respond better to user requests.

Comment: I thought maybe someone had figured that out :).

Thank you for your answer